# How to rewrite HTML for Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to re-write the code below so that it will use an image_tag. I know how to apply a class attribute, but how do I apply a custom attribute like "data-dark-logo"?

I'm learning how to develop and am building an application that has the following HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
  <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="external_assets/images/logo-dark.png">
    <img src="external_assets/images/logo.png" alt="Canvas Logo">
  </a>
  <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="external_assets/images/logo-dark@2x.png">
    <img src="external_assets/images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to rewrite this so it will function in my Rails app.

Comment: Show us what you've done of the rails part so far and I ca show you how to add a data attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
    <div id="logo">
    <%= link_to welcome_index_path, class: 'standard-logo', data: {'dark-logo' => asset_path("front/logo-dark.png") } do %>
        <%= image_tag("front/logo.png") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to welcome_index_path, class: 'retina-logo', data: {'dark-logo' => asset_path("front/logo-dark@2x.png") } do %>
        <%= image_tag("front/logo@2x.png") %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

But I'm not sure if this complies with Rails best practices

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the data attributes as a hash.

```
<%= link_to '/link', class: 'standard-logo', data: {'dark-logo' => 'external_assets/....' do %>
  <%= image_tag ('external_assets/...') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In this solution, is the 'data-dark-logo' isn't pulling from the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
<div id="logo">
    <%= link_to("index.html", class: "standard-logo", data-dark-logo: "external_assets/images/logo-dark.png") do %>
        <%= image_tag("external_assets/images/logo.png",    alt: "Canvas Logo") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to("index.html", class: "retina-logo",   data-dark-logo: "external_assets/images/logo-dark@2x.png") do %>
        <%= image_tag("external_assets/images/logo@2x.png", alt: "Canvas Logo") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

To make the data-dark-logo pull your asset from the asset pipeline, try using the asset_path helper:

```
<%= link_to("index.html", class: "standard-logo", data-dark-logo: asset_path("external_assets/images/logo-dark.png")) do %>
```

Comment: In this solution, is the 'data-dark-logo' isn't pulling from the asset pipeline?

Comment: No, it isn't. To make it pull from the asset pipeline, you need to put the images in the public/assets/images directory. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: Sorry, I just reread your comment and now I understand what you're asking. No, the data-dark-logo will just directly copy that path into the HTML.